# Perfect overlapping of dotted nodes in matrices

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

If you have a TikZ matrix of nodes, where every node is dotted, the dots do not overlap properly. Please see the attached code:

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,dotted}]
\matrix[matrix of nodes]{
text & text\\
text & text\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if you simply draw two nodes in the correct positions, the dots overlap correctly:

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node [draw,dotted,minimum size=20mm]at (0,0){text};
 \node [draw,dotted,minimum size=20mm]at (0,-2){text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is it possible to make the nodes inside the matrix to behave like those outside?

Comment: Hi sylvi, welcome to the site. It's really just a coincidence that the dots in your second picture line up perfectly: Try setting `minimum size=19mm`, you'll see that the dots are also out of sync.

Comment: oh... didn't notice that... So there is no way to force the desired overlapping?

Comment: One option would be to draw the dotted lines in afterwards.  Would that be acceptable?

Comment: as long as it doesn't interfere with the standard behavior of a matrix of nodes is acceptable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use Andrew Stacey's `matrixcells` package (which is [available on Launchpad](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/files)) to draw a proper grid between the cells, instead of drawing boxes around each cell:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz, matrixcells}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[
    matrix of nodes,
    inner sep=0pt,
    matrix grid=densely dotted,
    matrix border=densely dotted,
    cells={inner sep=0.3333em}
]{
text & text\\
text & text\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna test this and report back. Thankyou